# JTextField on Key Entered flashing black

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am making a game canvas using swing and decided to use `JTextField`'s for the input of a username and password into the panel.

I am buffering an image then rendering it onto the screen instead of drawing everything directly onto the panel real-time.

I have ran into a problem though, I paint a background and have set both of my text fields to opaque, but it seems that whenever I go to enter something into those text field's it flashes a black box where the `JTextField` is.

It happens in both of my username and password fields. Any idea of what the cause of this could be?

Other helpful information: Whenever I click on a text box, both of the components flash black where the first character would be.

EDIT -- I just noticed that the login button I have also flashes black when `MOUSE_ENTERED` and `MOUSE_EXIT`.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {


public GamePanel(int width, int height) {
    this.pWidth = width; 
    this.pHeight = height;

    setController(new LoginGameController(this));

    setPreferredSize( new Dimension(pWidth, pHeight));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();    // the JPanel now has focus, so receives key events

    // create game components

    addMouseListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);

    setLayout(null);

    startGame();
}
 private void startGame()
  // initialise and start the thread 
  { if (animator == null) {
      animator = new Thread(this);
      animator.start();
    }
  }

public void run() {
    while(true) {
          gameUpdate(); 
          if(getGraphics() != null){
              gameRender();   // render the game to a buffer
              paintScreen();  // draw the buffer on-screen
          }
          try {
            Thread.sleep(28);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

private void paintScreen() {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();

    if ((g != null) && (img != null))
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}

private void gameRender() {
    if(getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0)
        img = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());

    if(img != null) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight);

        getController().render(img);

        paintComponents(img.getGraphics());


    }
}

}
```

Here is text fields: (from a seperate class entirely calling to the GamePanel using getPanel()...)

```
//Setup Login fields
    usernameTF = new JTextField();
    usernameTF.setOpaque(false);
    usernameTF.getCaret().setBlinkRate(0);
    usernameTF.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    usernameTF.setBounds(USERNAME_FIELD);
    usernameTF.setBorder(null);
    getPanel().add(usernameTF);

    passwordTF = new JPasswordField();
    passwordTF.setOpaque(false);
    passwordTF.getCaret().setBlinkRate(0);
    passwordTF.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    passwordTF.setBounds(PASSWORD_FIELD);
    passwordTF.setBorder(null);
    getPanel().add(passwordTF);

    loginBtn = new JButton();
    loginBtn.setOpaque(false);
    loginBtn.setBackground(null);
    loginBtn.setBorder(null);
    loginBtn.setBounds(LOGIN_BUTTON);
    loginBtn.addMouseListener(getPanel());
    getPanel().add(loginBtn);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It "sounds" like an issue with opacity and/all painting.  Want to paste some sample code so we can stop guessing

Comment: Looks like you've got a bug in your code. I'm betting that you're going to have to show some of it to get a decent answer though I hope I'm wrong. Best would be an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your code is worrying me a little, would it be possible to see at least the main rendering implementation and how you construct the UI, please

Comment: Check out the current revision? I hope that helps, its all I can give at the moment without way too much code. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Again, best would be an [sscce](http://sscce.org). If you get a decent answer soon, then fine, please ignore this recommendation, but if not, it will greatly increase your chances of getting a decent answer soon.

Comment: That webpage isn't loading for me and I tried googling it with no luck Hovercraft. And yes, I tried to use Is it just me or is it down for everyone, and its not just me.

Comment: Please don't delete information from your question. Realize that it's not just *your* question but belongs to all with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is, you circumventing Swings repaint process and not honoring the EDT when you up-date your graphics.

`JComponent#getGraphics` is a temporary/scratch buffer which will be re-draw on the next repaint.  Also, if you didn't create the graphics, you shouldn't dispose it!

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
          gameUpdate(); 
          if(getGraphics() != null){
              gameRender();   // render the game to a buffer
              try {
                  SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          paintScreen();  // draw the buffer on-screen
                      }
                  });
              } catch (Exception exp) {
                  exp.printStackTrace(); // please clean this up
              }
          }
          try {
            Thread.sleep(28);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will fix it, but it can't hurt. (This WILL effect you FPS and you should be taking into consideration how long it took to paint and how long you want to wait)

Alternativly, rather then calling `paintScreen()`, you could call `repaint` (or have `paintScreen` do it) and override the `paintComponent` method to paint your buffer.

This would allow Swing to resume control over the paint process properly.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, I took your advice and made it so that I am just overriding the paint(Graphics g) method in the Panel, it works a lot better, with the occasional flash. But, I actually have an idea of why that could be. I imagine that the img field isnt finished being pained on when the paint(Graphics) method is called so their being unsynced. However, I am very grateful to you for help!

Comment: @cdog: no, don't override `paint(...)` else you will lose double buffering and get very choppy animation. Instead override a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method as MadProgrammer already recommended(!), and don't forget to call the super method.

Comment: there is a way to disable the repainting process, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 2):

A window or component has at least three ways to repaint.

1. on demand from the operating system when it has lost a part of the window buffer.
2. on demand from a library component when it has changed its state.
3. manually by manipulating its own frame buffer.

normally, the following pathway is active:

The operating system may request a particular rectangle to be updated. This is picked up by the toolkit. Additionally, a component may signal its change to the toolkit as well through its `repaint` method. The toolkit keeps collecting an merging incoming repaint requests for a while then asks the window to repaint a particular rectangle. The default action for the window is to paint itself by calling its `paintComponent` method where it doesn't overlap with solid children and then paint its components recursively.

If you do your own rendering, *the toolkit is doing it as well*. Since you didn't override your `paintComponent`, when this method runs, it acts as default. The default action is to do nothing. The toolkit then picks up the empty frame buffer and paints the button (which doesn't paint its background) over it.

You can disable the toolkit's rendering process and do all rendering yourself (grab a buffer, paint into it, then submit). You can call the [`setIgnoreRepaint(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setIgnoreRepaint%28boolean%29) method to ignore the requests by OS.